# Adding border-bottom to a div

Tags: html, css

I have a icon and some text wrapped around a div called "content_item" but when I try adding a border to the 5 items it doesn't work properly and all the borders get squished on top. I'm doing this for 5 divs sharing the same class and all the borders get squished together. [image]

CSS code:

```
.content_item {
 color: rgb(44, 103, 181);
 border-bottom: solid red;
}
```

HTML code:

```
                <div class="content_item">
                    <div class="content_icon"><i class="ss-icon">doc</i></div>
                    <div class="content_text">
                        <p>How to Retain Good Employees</p>
                        <p><em>1 day ago</em></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Are you floating the divs? You may need a clearfix solution

Comment: Yes this looks like a clearfix situation

Comment: I am floating the divs. How do I add the clearfix so it applies to all?

Comment: @stack_newbie23 I am assuming you are using `float` then why not used `overflow:hidden` on parent element which will solve your problem. check the DEMO. http://jsbin.com/yiyosuve/1/edit

Comment: @KheemaPandey that worked! How did you know I needed to do that?

Comment: I had also faced this problem at my learning stage. let me make it answer so you may accept that.

Comment: Sounds good please do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using `float` then why not used `overflow:hidden` on parent element which will solve your problem. Also you can use `clearfix` Method.

check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yiyosuve/1/edit)** for more clear picture.

Comment: What signals to you that that's what you need to do? I've used floats other places and it hasn't been a problem